# how can login by php sql in android?

Tags: android

I want to login by php in android
I have this code but it doesnt work
I dont know what is the reason
Any help to fix thes code??

```html
package com.ust.autism;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class OfMainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText et, pass;
    TextView text1;
    String send_num;
    HttpPost httppost;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(OfMainActivity.this, "",
                "التحقق من اسم المستخدم ...", true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                login(); // نفذ الدالة داخل الثريد اي في خلفية التطبيق ..
            }
        }).start();
    }

    void login() {
        try {

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/sync.php"); // رابط مسار ملف الربط سواء كان على السيرفر او استضافة إلخ
            //اضافة البيانات
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2);
            // المتغيرات التي كتبها المستخدم
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", et.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass.getText().toString().trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //تنفيذ HTTP
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // جلب الرسالة التي يظهرها ملف الربط مع القاعدة
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    text1.setText(response); // ضع الرسالة التي تأتي من ملف الربط مكان النص
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")) { // لاحظ الرسالة هنا هي نفسها التي موجودة في ملف الربط مع القاعدة
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(OfMainActivity.this, "تم تسجيل الدخول بنجاح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
// اذا تم تسجيل الدخول بنجاح أذهب إلى الصفحة الرئيسية وخذ معك اسم المستخدم
                Intent i = new Intent(OfMainActivity.this, Elevel.class);
                send_num = et.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("text", send_num);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the logcat details

Comment: We can't point out what you should do if we don't know where your problem lies. Anyway there is a good tutorial in android hive on how to do this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code for login in your post service...

```
private class LoginAysnc extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private ProgressDialog regDialog=null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            regDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
            regDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            regDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.app_pleasewait));
            regDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            regDialog.setCancelable(true);
            regDialog.show();
        }       
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try 
            {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                                et.getText().toString().trim()));
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                                pass.getText().toString()));

                        String response = null;
                        try {
                            response = SimpleHttpClient
                                    .executeHttpPost("http://localhost/sync.php",
                                            postParameters);
                             res = response.toString();

                             return res;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);


                //  error.setText(resp);
                    if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(regDialog!=null)
            {

                regDialog.dismiss();

                System.out.println("PostId:-"+str_postid);

                }

  // do what u do
    }
```

SimpleHttpClient.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class SimpleHttpClient {
 /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

    /** Single instance of our HttpClient */
    private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

    /**
     * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
     *
     * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
     */
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
    }

    public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    }


    public static String executeHttpatch(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```